# DataTable How to put id on a button?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I just started learning datatables only today and I read much infos on FAQs in their website but can't find any solutions there.

I'm trying to put on a button with id getting (`data[0]`). On click a div with id+data[0] will collapse containing options and forms for the selected row..

I wanted to put a button and div with ID same with row `data[0]`. For instance I wanted to archive,edit or delete the specific row using the id.

For better understanding

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
var dataTable = $('#testT').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{
                    url :"search_e_que.php",
                    type: "post" 
                     
                },
                "columnDefs": [ {
                            "targets": -1,
                            "data": null,
                            "defaultContent": "\
                                    <button class='btn btn-outline-dark' type='button' id='arcb-' title='Archive'>\
                                        <span class='fa fa-file-archive'></span>\
                                    </button>\
                                    <div class='collapse' id='arcc-'>\
                                        Possible Options Here\
                                    </div>",

                 },
                 {
                 // hide id_number column
                 "targets":[0],
                 "visible":false,
                 "searchable":false
                 } ],
            } );

             $('#testT tbody').on( 'click', '#arcb-', function () {
                var data = dataTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
                var id_tag = $(this).attr('id')+data[0];
                var holder_tag = $('#arcc-').attr('id')+data[0];
                 
                $('#arcc-').collapse();
            } );
```

Any suggestions or debug options will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: please try and fix your wording because it's impossible to follow what you're wanting and so it's going to be hard to help you. If you want to set an element's id you can do so using document.getElementById(id-here).id = new-id-here;

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to put a button and div with ID same with row data[0]. For instance I wanted to archive,edit or delete the specific row using the id .. thanks for the fast response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. columns.render did the trick.

```
"columnDefs": [{
          "data":null,
          "render":function(data, type, row, meta){
             return data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5];
          }},
         {
            "targets":-1,
            "data":null,
             "render":function(data, type, row, meta){
             return "
                <button class='btn btn-outline-dark' type='button' data-toggle='collapse' name='arcb' data-target='#arcc-"+data[0]+"' id='arcb-"+data[0]+"' title='Archive'>\
                    <span class='fa fa-file-archive text-warning'></span>\
                </button>\
                <div class='row collapse' id='arcc-"+data[0]+"' name='arcc'>\
                        <form method='POST' name='archiveEmp' action='../../admin/employee/archiveEmployee.php'>\
                            <div class='form-group col-sm-12'>\
                                <label id='eTitle-"+data[0]+"'>Effectivity Date:</label>\
                                <input id='eDate-"+data[0]+"' type='date' name='archiveEffectDate' class='form-control' max='2999-12-31' required />\
                                </div>\
                            <div class='form-group col-sm-12'>\
                                <label id='aTitle-"+data[0]+"'>Archive Status :</label>\
                                <select id='a-status-"+data[0]+"' name='archive' class='form-control mb-3' required>\
                                    <option value ='-----''>-- Select Status--</option>\
                                    <option value ='AWOL'>AWOL</option>\
                                    <option value ='Deceased'>Deceased</option>\
                                    <option value ='Resigned'>Resigned</option>\
                                    <option value ='Retired'>Retired </option>\
                                    <option value ='Terminated'>Terminated</option>\
                                    <option value ='Transferred'>Transferred</option>\
                                    </select>\
                                <div class='text-right col-sm-12'>\
                                    <button class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Archive Employee' type='submit' id='btnOk-"+data[0]+"' name='btnArc'><span class='fa fa-archive'></span> Archive </button>\
                                    <button class='btn btn-danger'  data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#arcc-"+data[0]+"' title='Cancel' type='button' id='btnCancel-"+data[0]+"'><span class='fa fa-ban'></span> Cancel</button>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                            <input type='hidden' name='empIDHold' value='"+data[0]+"'/>\
                            <input type='hidden' name='isActive' value='0'/>\
                        </form>\
                </div>\
                ";
          }



         }, 
         {
 // hide id_number column
 "targets":[0],
 "visible":false,
 "searchable":false,
 },
 {
 "targets":[3],
 "searchable":false
 }],

"order": [[ 4, "asc" ]],
```